# How do you make a self-referential arrow with diagrams?

Tags: haskell, haskell-diagrams

I would like to do something like this:

```
p = p2 (0,0)
shaft = arc xDir (-5/6 @@ turn)
example = ( arrowBetween' (with & arrowShaft .~ shaft) p p)
```

But, of course, I get an error: "Scale by zero!  Halp!"

I understand why this doesn't work with the existing implementation of `arrowBetween'`, since it calls `arrow'`, which scales the shaft by the difference between the endpoints.  However, this *should* be possible.  It's not that uncommon to see an arrow loop back around to where it started in diagrams.

Comment: http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/arrow.html there is an example in the section Connecting points on the trace of diagrams

Comment: Right, but in this example the endpoints are merely close together.  What if they are the same?

Comment: There is an issue about this currently: https://github.com/diagrams/diagrams-lib/issues/151